# PHP - load .php page of a particular get[] variable into a particular div?

Tags: php, html, get, include

I know this is an easy one but it's been a long time since i've done php.

I have 2 types of links. one using `$_get[]` of `p`, and other `g`.
like:

```
<a href='?p=pages/page-type-1'>page 1</a>
<a href='?g=pages/page-type-2'>page 2</a>
```

after clicking on a particular link , I want to load .php pages in divs of particular ids through the `include('')` method.

Thank you so much.

Comment: You should be very careful doing this; it's trivial to guess paths to critical files on the server and have your script serve them up to the end-user. Regarding the technical question, do you want the page to perform a full refresh with the new content loaded, or would this be asynchronous via JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

```
if($_GET['p'] === 'pages/page-type-1') {
  include('page-to-include.php');
}
```

Whatever you do, DO NOT pass variables from $_GET to include.  This is extremely dangerous! You cannot trust data being supplied in $_GET and so you always want to test it specifically and avoid passing it into other code unless you have to.

Also notice the use of === to force both a value check AND a type check.  Look up === operator on PHP.net if you aren't familiar with this.

Comment: I will add that if you really must do it, you can pass variables from $_GET to include, but its extremely dangerous.  You need to be very very careful about what you're doing.  Its best to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You said that you wan to load the pages in a particular div ids right? You can achieve this by using AJAX..

In your .js file write like this.

```
    $.ajax({
     type:POST,
     url:'path/of/your/php/file/for/requesting/data.php',
     success:function(data){
      var get_data = parseJSON(data);

      //Target the specific div you want to display your requested data that returned to you by your php.

        $('#divid').html(get_data.name);

     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['p']) && ($_GET['p'] === pages/page-type-1){
require_once 'some.php';
}
```

If you want to do anything with your GET data sanitize it first.Never trust your user

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this isn't quite your question, but a solution could be just use 1 GET variable for both pages, and then use a switch to determine which page you want:

```
if (isset($_GET["p"]))
{
    switch ($_GET["p"])
    {
        case "pages/page-type-1":
            include("page-type-1.php");
            break;

        case "pages/page-type-2":
            include("page-type-2.php");
            break;

        default:
            include("page-not-found.php");
    }
}
```